# Show more post stanleywp theme WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I'm using stanleywp theme for WordPress to display some post, actually I've inserted 20 posts, but it shows only 10posts.

This is what I did:

1. Portfolio -> Portfolio categories -> I added "brands" category
2. Portfolio -> add new -> and I've added 20 posts and set "brands" category

when I go to `.../portfolio-category/brands/` I should see all my 20 posts, but I see only 10.

How can I solve that?

This is `taxonomy-portfolio_cats.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>


   <div class="container pt">

      <div class="row mt">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 centered">
           <h1><?php echo single_term_title(); ?></h1>
           <hr>
           <?php if(category_description()) { ?>
           <?php echo category_description( ); ?>
           <?php } ?>
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row mt centered">
    <?php $cont = 0; ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
       <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
       <a class="zoom green" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
          <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
      </a>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if(bi_get_data('project_title', '5')) {?>
  <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
  <?php } ?>
</div> <!-- /col -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div>


<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's due to the default pagination (10 posts per page): you could increase the value on `Settings > Reading > Blog pages show at most`, or insert the pagination after `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>`, something like:

```
<?php
// Previous/next page navigation.
the_posts_pagination( array(
    'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'your-textdomain' ),
    'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'your-textdomain' ),
    'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'your-textdomain' ) . ' </span>',
) );
?>
```

Or if you want to change the number of posts per page only for that taxonomy archive you can use the [`pre_get_posts` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Changing_the_number_of_posts_per_page.2C_by_post_type):

```
function portfolio_cats_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    if ( is_tax( 'portfolio_cats' ) ) {
        // Display all posts in one page
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'portfolio_cats_posts_per_page', 1 );
```